# Object used as "self" argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, methods

I'm in the process of learning Python through a book, one of the questions was to create a class called Country which held the parameters shown below, then to create a method called is_larger that would return a boolean indicating whether the first country was larger, in area, than the other considering this code:

```
>>> canada = Country( 'Canada', 34482779, 9984670)
>>> usa = Country( 'United States of America' , 313914040, 9826675)
>>> canada. is_larger(usa)
True
```

Here's the solution from the book:

```
class Country():

    def __init__(self, name, population, area):
        """ (Country, str, int, int)

        A new Country named name with population people and area area.

        >>> canada = Country('Canada', 34482779, 9984670)
        >>> canada.name
        'Canada'
        >>> canada.population
        34482779
        >>> canada.area
        9984670
        """ 

        self.name = name
        self.population = population
        self.area = area

    def is_larger(self, other):
        """ (Country, Country) -> bool

        Return whether this country is larger than other.

        >>> canada = Country('Canada', 34482779, 9984670)
        >>> usa = Country('United States of America', 313914040, 9826675)
        >>> canada.is_larger(usa)
        True
        >>> usa.is_larger(canada)
        False
        """ 

        return self.area > other.area
```

I can apply this after seeing the answer, but I just don't understand the process and I'm keen on fully understanding the code. 
Method is_larger holds two parameters, one being *self*. Should the method not be:

```
def is_larger(self, country1, country2):
```

How was an object used as the *self* parameter?

If my question is confusing, please let me know and I'll try to clarify what's going on in my head lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call

```
canada.is_larger(usa)
```

can be thought of as syntactic sugar for

```
Country.is_larger(canada, usa)
```

The parameter `self` (really, the first argument to the method, regardless of what you name it) refers to the object that *invokes* the method. Here, whether you use the first form or the second form, `self == canada` and `other == usa`.